# Why would anyone use printf to output html instead of breaking out of PHP into the actual html?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, syntax, printf

Look at this horrible-to-look-at code from wordpress's twentyten theme:

```
<?php
function twentyten_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted on</span> %2$s <span class="meta-sep">by</span> %3$s', 'twentyten' ),
        'meta-prep meta-prep-author',
        sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><span class="entry-date">%3$s</span></a>',
            get_permalink(),
            esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
            get_the_date()
        ),
        sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s" title="%2$s">%3$s</a></span>',
            get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ),
            sprintf( esc_attr__( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentyten' ), get_the_author() ),
            get_the_author()
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Why would anyone want to do that??

Why not do the following instead?

```
<?php
function twentyten_posted_on() {
    ?>
    <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author">Posted on</span>
    <a href="<?php= get_permalink() ?>" title="<?php= esc_attr( get_the_time() ) ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <span class="entry-date">get_the_date()</span>
    </a>
    <span class="meta-sep">by</span>
    <span class="author vcard">
        <a class="url fn n" href="<?php= get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ?>" title="<?php= esc_attr__( 'View all posts by '.get_the_author() ) ?>"><?php= get_the_author() ?></a>
    </span>
    <?php
}
?>
```

The latter is much cleaner to me. Why would anyone use the first method instead? Is it just personal preference, or is there some functional benefit?

Comment: It's strange having `sprintf` nested inside a `printf`, but I often use `printf` to output formatted numerical data in HTML. I think `printf` is great.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely useful IN the html, but for actually outputting html like that it seems a little messy hehe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's written the way it is so it can be internationalized. You'll see that, inside the call to `printf()`, there's a call to `__()`, which is WordPress' translation function.

This way, the translators can easily move the portions of each string around, by just moving the `%1$s` parts, to comply with their language's grammar and structure. Then, the translated formatting string is passed to `printf()`, which can insert the appropriate variables.

[WordPress' doc page on translation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#Messages_With_Placeholders) has some examples of the translator side of this (albeit with simpler strings).

Not all of what's going on there is strictly necessary for the translation, but since they're doing some things printf-style already, I guess the theory is that it's easier to understand if it's at least consistent.

Comment: Oh, ok. thanks! That explains a lot! So in my case though, that is only helpful if I've selected a different language for my blog. I bet then that many wordpress themes don't do well for translation. On the other hand, people will usually design an html template for their own language anyway.

Comment: Many people's custom themes for their own sites just ignore localization, since they just want English. Of course, TwentyTen makes sure to support it because it's the official default theme. Themes designed to be shared would also generally be expected to support translations.

Comment: That makes sense. So it works out of the box for whatever language.

Answer (score 1):

I's only a matter of personal taste. The author using sprintf may have preferred it because it separates presentation from logic. I find your way easier to read (I also prefer to avoid using short open tags).

Comment: No, it wouldn't have been separating presentation from logic. It still has presentation merged into the logic, but it's just hidden in a string rather than broken out into a non-PHP block.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to render. I personally use `sprintf` and `printf` when the first argument is a variable string, or a localized string.

On a side note, the real problem with this code sample is how it outputs HTML from inside a function.... I would have used a "view" file instead (ex: `include $view_file;`) so the code is properly separated and organised.